# How do you import CSS from node_modules in react?

Tags: reactjs, npm, mern, reactstrap

I'm following along to a youtube tutorial to learn the MERN stack. Currently i'm trying to import boostrap css in my App.js file. But i keep getting this error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPT75.png)

Here is my App.js file

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppNavbar from './components/AppNavbar';


import './App.css';
import 'boostrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppNavbar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I ran `npm install --save boostrap` before attempting to include it, ive also restarted the server. All to no avail. Is there a new way to include css from the node_modules folder?

Comment: You wrote boostrap . It should be bootstrap, Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to import `bootstrap` into your react project. You can import the css file into your `App.js` like this.

`import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

The import statement is not finding the file(s) do to the path passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, use this

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```